# How can I get the text of an error code?

Tags: php, error-handling, exception

I want to print "Parse error", "Fatal error", "Warning" instead of `$exception->getCode()`, How can I do it?

```
function exception_handler( $exception ) 
{

    /*
     * Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'w' (T_STRING), expecting ';' or '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\dermaquality\aplicacion\vista\paginas\Dermaquality\proceso\indicadores.php on line 25
     */


    //echo $exception->__toString();
    echo "<strong>" . $exception->getCode() . ": " . $exception->getMessage() . " in " . $exception->getFile() . " on line " . $exception->getLine() . "</strong><br/>\n";
    echo str_replace( '#', '<br/>#', $exception->getTraceAsString() );
}

set_exception_handler('exception_handler');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the function [error_get_last](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php) that return the last error.

```
<?php
echo $a;
print_r(error_get_last());
?>
```

That will print

```
Array
(
[type] => 8
[message] => Undefined variable: a
[file] => C:\WWW\index.php
[line] => 2
)
```